# 22.04.1 sliding bottom dock panel

Tags: dock

While still yesterday on 20.04, I was able to slide the dock panel at the bottom of my screen with a mouse scroll, in 22.04.1 I can't do it anymore. The scroll sliding works only once the dock panel is on the sides of the screen, rather than on its bottom.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your mouse scrolls vertically. The horizontal task bar therefore will not react on that. b.t.w., I have to do utmost effort to fill an entire horizontal taskbar on a normal HD screen.

Comment: You write that my mouse scrolls vertically. OK, but somehow in 20.04 my scroll worked in the bottom dock as well.

Comment: You could check how it behaves in Xorg. Ubuntu 22.04 by default runs on Wayland. It may be a difference in behavior caused by Wayland.

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason, it turns out, rather than Wayland, I have X11. Also, it's a bit inconsistent, but I still can move horizontally in open-folder windows with my mouse scroll.